# Use flat_map to convert Vec<u8> to Vec<char>

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

I'm stuck in a similar situation to [Borrow-check error with variable not living long enough in nested lambda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33600843/borrow-check-error-with-variable-not-living-long-enough-in-nested-lambda) but am unable to figure out how my situation differs:

```
let mut vec = vec![vec![0u8, 1u8], vec![2u8, 3u8], vec![4u8, 5u8]];
vec.iter().map(|row| {
    row.iter()
        .map(|d| format!("{:04b}", d))
        .flat_map(|s| s.chars())
        .collect::<Vec<_>>()
});
```

Which gives the error:

```
error[E0597]: `s` does not live long enough
 --> src/main.rs:6:35
  |
6 |             .flat_map(|s| s.chars())
  |                           -       ^ `s` dropped here while still borrowed
  |                           |
  |                           borrow occurs here
7 |             .collect::<Vec<_>>()
  |                                - borrowed value needs to live until here
```

I worked around it by creating a new `Vec` and appending, but I'm unclear why the first approach did not work.

```
let mut tmp = vec![];
vec.iter()
    .map(|d| format!("{:04b}", d))
    .for_each(|s| {tmp.append(&mut s.chars().collect::<Vec<_>>());});
```

Comment: When you call `chars()`, you borrow `s` to create a `Char` struct that hold a reference on it. When you exit the closure, s is dropped, and thus `Char` is invalidated.

Comment: @Boiethios This is the exact way that the [documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.flat_map) does it though. Why does it work there and not here?

Comment: @Andrew That example uses static strings.  In your example, the strings are created within the iterator, so they don't live long enough.

Comment: See [How can I store a Chars iterator in the same struct as the String it is iterating on?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43952104/155423) for a version of `.chars()` that would transfer ownership of the `String` and thus work in this case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You first map the closure `|d| format!("{:04b}", d)` over your iterator, yielding `String`s, which own their data, so this works perfectly find.  The `flat_map()` in the next step calls `.chars()` on each `String`.  This implicitly derefrences the `String` to an `&str`, and creates a `Chars` iterator referencing this borrow.  But now we have a problem – nobody is owning the `String` that we borrowed anymore.

One workaround is to store a temporary vector of `String`s:

```
let mut vec = vec![vec![0u8, 1u8], vec![2u8, 3u8], vec![4u8, 5u8]];
vec.iter().map(|row| {
    let strings: Vec<_> = row
        .iter()
        .map(|d| format!("{:04b}", d))
        .collect();
    strings
        .iter()
        .flat_map(|s| s.chars())
        .collect::<Vec<_>>()
});
```

Now we have an owner for the intermediary `String`s, and everything works fine again.

Comment: Maybe we should have a consuming version of `chars` for `String` to prevent this kind of boilerplate.

Comment: @Boiethios: I was surprised just yesterday to realize that I could not find a `FromIterator` implementation for that.

Comment: @MatthieuM. Seems trivial to do. If this addition does not induce any breaking change, maybe someone (You? I?) should propose something.

Comment: @Boiethios: Please go ahead :)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I'm only 2 weeks into rust so still learning ownership. Slowly. So because [chars](https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/alloc/str.rs.html#685) is from the `StrExt` trait which is implemented on `str` and not `String`, it gets converted from `String` to `str`, through `Deref<Target = str>` then passed in to `chars(&self)`? meaning if there was a version of `chars(self)` it would work?

Comment: @Andrew Exactly, you summarized perfectly the issue :)